# Select All Checkboxes in a Dropdown

Tags: node.js, protractor, multi-select

I am new to node.js / protractor and want to select select all checkboxes in a dropdown. My code works but there is a problem with 2 of the items that have the same text. When selected, both are checked. In my code I want to skip these 2 items but my text comparison isn't working.

Since selecting one of these duplicate items checks both, selecting the second one un-selects both. For simplicity I'd prefer to merely skip these when they are found in the forEach loop.

```
element.all(by.xpath('//*[@id="work-bench"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div[3]/ul')).all(by.className('checkbox')).then(function(totalDCs) {                                
    console.log('DCs in Dropdown List ' + (totalDCs.length));
    DCCount = totalDCs.length;
});

element.all(by.className('multiselect__element')).then(function(options) {
    var i = 0; 
    var j = 1;
    options.forEach(function(option) {
        option.getText().then(function(text) {
            console.log(text + ' was selected');
            i++;                                   
            if(text != 'FULFILLMENT') {
                option.click();
                if(DCCount-j == i) {
                    return DCCount;
                }
            }
            else {
                j++;
                console.log('j equals ' + j);
            }    
        });
    });
});
```

The line if(text != 'FULFILLMENT') doesn't recognize the match and thus performs the selection (twice).

Comment: Try using `!text.includes('FULFILLMENT')` instead. My guess is `FULFILLMENT` isn't an exact match so the condition is returning true when it shouldn't.

Comment: if(text !== 'FULFILLMENT') worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
if(text !== 'FULFILLMENT')
```

or

```
if(!text.localeCompare('FULFILLMENT'))
```

and tell us if that works for you